# asp.net mvc database relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have simple database. Let i add using `AddBookName` record in table `NamesSet` database should generate random BookNameID. The main question is how to figure out the `BookNameID` that was generated to establish a connection to table `Books`?

[image]

Books:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BooksSet] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[BookNameID] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[PlaceID]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_BooksSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Names

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NamesSet] (
[BookNameID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[BookName]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Language]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NamesSet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookNameID] ASC)
);
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    TestEntities TE = new TestEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBookName(Names name)
    {
        TE.NamesSet.Add(name);
        TE.SaveChanges();
        return View();
    }

}
```

View:

```
@model TestDataBase.Models.Names
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using(@Html.BeginForm("AddBookName","Home"))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.BookName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Language)
    <input type="submit" value="Add name"/>
}
```

Comment: After you call `SaveChanges()`, isn't the `BookNameID` property on `name` populated with the generated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `SaveChanges()`, any objects added to the context will be populated with the generated values from the database.  So the generated value should be available after that line, in:

```
name.BookNameID
```